# Как в код php вставить css

Tags: php, html, css

Скрипты создает список меню подставляя первое слово сам. Вот это слово и нужно оформить в css, но вот как вставить в php стили не знаю. подскажите.
Вот код:

```
    public function getProfileMenu($profile){

    $menu = array(
        array(
            'title' => ($profile['nickname']),
            'url' => href_to($this->name, $profile['id']),
            'url_mask' => href_to($this->name, $profile['id']),
        )
    );
```

Надо к nickname добавить стили (то есть в php вставить html).

Comment: Код в стили вставляется так: <style><?php  echo "вставка"; ?></style>

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, само по себе вставление CSS в PHP - очень плохая практика. Мировое сообщество в конце концов все больше и больше идет к концепции разделения ответственности. Храните логику в PHP, а стили оставьте в каскадных таблицах. Самое распространенное решение для ситуации, подобной Вашей - обернуть необходимое в какой-нибудь строчной элемент с классом и уже в стилях, по-человечески описать, что же вы от него хотите.

```
array(
      'title' => ('<span class="table-title">' . $profile['nickname'] . '</span>'),
       'url' => href_to($this->name, $profile['id']),
       'url_mask' => href_to($this->name, $profile['id']),
    )
```

Затем в style.css, или как оно у Вас называется:

```
.table-title {
//Ваши стили будут здесь
}
```

И PHP-код сохраните чище. И подобных вопросов возникать не будет. Но если уж совсем нетерпится иметь css в исходном выводе HTML, @Akainq сказал все верно

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант через атрибут style:

```php
  public function getProfileMenu($profile){

    $menu = array(
        array(
            'title' => ("<span  style='color: red;'>".$profile['nickname']."</span>"),
            'url' => href_to($this->name, $profile['id']),
            'url_mask' => href_to($this->name, $profile['id']),
        )
    );
```